# Unable to execute Struts 2 program with ModelDriven interceptor

Tags: java, xml, jsp, struts2, model-driven

I am new to Struts 2 framework. I have made a program for understanding `modelDriven` interceptor. But I am unable to execute it. Following are the list of files and in the end there is a output (error).

**index.jsp:**

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%-- <jsp:useBean id="ent" class="pack.Entity" scope="session" /> --%>
    <s:form method="get" action="go">
        <s:textfield name="t1" label="Name"></s:textfield>
        <s:password name="p1" label="Password"></s:password>
        <s:submit value="accept"></s:submit>
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Entity.java:**

```java
package actions_pack;

public class Entity {
private String t1;
private String p1;
public String getP1() {
    return p1;
}

public void setP1(String p1) {
    this.p1 = p1;
}

public Entity() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public String getT1() {
    return t1;
}

public void setT1(String t1) {
    this.t1 = t1;
}

}
```

**GoAction.java:**

```java
package actions_pack;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStack;
public class GoAction implements ModelDriven<Entity> {
    private Entity en;

    public Entity getEn() {
        return en;
    }
    public void setEn(Entity en) {
        this.en = en;
    }
    public String execute(){
        System.out.println("inside action");
        if(en.getT1().equalsIgnoreCase("nitin")){
            return "success";
        }
        else{
            return "failure";
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Entity getModel() {
        System.out.println("inside model driven....");
        en=new Entity();
        return en;
    }
}
```

**struts.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="dd">
            <result-types>
            <result-type name="dispatcher"
                class="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult"
                default="true" />
        </result-types>
        <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="modelDriven" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor"/>
        <interceptor-stack name="myStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"></interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>
        <action name="go" class="actions_pack.GoAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="myStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result name="success" type="dispatcher" >/one/welcome.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure" type="dispatcher">/one/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**welcome.jsp:**

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Welcome, <s:property value="t1"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**web-page output(500 error):**

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
    actions_pack.GoAction.execute(GoAction.java:24)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.34 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
```

In `struts.xml` file I don't want to use/extend `struts-default` package. Although, when I include `params` interceptor entry along with `modelDriven` interceptor in `struts.xml`, problem solves. What is the reason behind this. Can any one guide me?

Comment: Do you have a reason not to use/extend `struts-default.xml`?

Comment: No. No reason. But, I wanted to ask, why does problem solves, on adding `params` interceptor; even when when I am not extending `struts-default` package from `struts-default.xml` file.

Comment: For clarity, just tell in which order your interceptors are invoked if any.

Comment: with one interceptor `ModelDriven`, I am getting 500 error code as seen in output. But, when I add `params` interceptor below `ModelDriven`, problem goes away. why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a property in the action class that needs initialize prior to the action execution. You can do it in many ways.

The way you have chosen relies on [`modelDriven` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/model-driven-interceptor.html) which is running before your action is executed. It invokes `getModel()` to push it on `top` of the `valueStack`. So, your entity property is being initialized. If you remove this interceptor you will get `NullPointerException` when the action is executed.

If your `Entity` is a simple POJO that you can instantiate yourself then simply do it inline instead of in `getModel()`.

```
private Entity en = new Entity();     

@Override
public Entity getModel() {
    System.out.println("inside model driven....");
    return en;
}
```

Next part is about [`params` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html). It uses OGNL to populate a `top` object that is a model if you have used [`modelDriven` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/model-driven-interceptor.html) prior [`params` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html).

Living it along with your action allows to initialize some properties you reference in the `execute()`.

For example `t1` should be initialized.

Comment: Still getting 500 error code. I removed `ModelDriven<Entity>` interface from my `GoAction.java` file. Made class variable `private Entity en=new Entity();` in `GoAction.java`. Also removed `ModelDriven` interceptor entry from `struts.xml` file. Still same error code.

Comment: Yes, that was not enough, you could have null pointer exception in two ways. See updated.

Comment: @JSK If this answer helped you to solve your problem, please consider accept and upvote it.